# How do you count the number of parameters for AIC?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, aic, information-theory

Suppose I have an $n$ by $10$ data matrix $X$ and a continuous target $y$. I want to compare 2 models: $m_0$, which is an OLS regression model, and $m_1$, which is a deep neural network with $10^6$ weights. The network is maximizing Gaussian likelihood, same as for OLS, and I would like to use AIC as the comparison metric.

For OLS the number of parameters would be $10+1$, but what do I use for the neural network? It seems to me that requiring one extra nat of log-likelihood per parameter is an enormous cost for networks with millions of weights. And what about things like the optimizer and dropout? Technically that's a decision made based on your data, so would those be counted as extra parameters?

Comment: As far as the d.f., Ye's (1998) notion of generalized degrees of freedom might help, though actually computing the approximate d.f. may take some computational effort (unless you can get a good approximation direct from the training you already did); you need to compute / approximate $\sum_i \frac{\partial \hat{y}_i}{\partial y_i}$. This wouldn't count the variance parameter(s), but if they're the same for all models, the differences in AIC wouldn't be impacted by that. There may also be some issues on whether the AIC's own conditions/assumptions apply, so you might need to look at that, too.